# Slot not called for QSplashScreen

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I'm trying to show a start-up image using `QSplashScreen` and I want to show the image for about 2 seconds.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(":/images/usm.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
     splash.showMessage("Loading Processes");
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, &splash, SLOT(close()));
    MainWindow w;
      w.show();

    splash.finish(&w);
    return a.exec();
}
```

But this is not working. `QSplashScreen` appears for some milliseconds and then disappears. Tried to modify the time period but it seems like the `QSplashScreen` object is not connected to slot. What's the problem and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the timer is not blocking the execution so the splash screen has already closed with the `splash.finish(&w)` call. What you need is a sleep. You could use a `QWaitCondition` like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSplashScreen splash(QPixmap(":/images/usm.png"));
    splash.show();
    splash.showMessage("Loading Processes");

    // Wait for 2 seconds
    QMutex dummyMutex;
    dummyMutex.lock();
    QWaitCondition waitCondition;
    waitCondition.wait(&dummyMutex, 2000);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    splash.finish(&w);
    return a.exec();
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is that you are blocking the execution. If you do not want to block it then you can simply **remove** the `splash.finish(&w)` call:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(":/images/usm.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
    splash.showMessage("Loading Processes");
    QTimer::singleShot(2000, &splash, SLOT(close()));
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to make your MainWindow emit a signal when it's done initializing, and connect that to the splash screen.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSplashScreen splash(QPixmap(":/images/usm.png"));
    splash.showMessage("Loading Processes");
    splash->show();

    QMainWindow w;

    QTimer::singleShot(2000, splash, SLOT(close()));
    QTimer::singleShot(2500, &w, SLOT(show()));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: well main window appears normall, but QSplashScreen still does not work as needs